# Input data in C

Tags: c, string

I have problem with handling input in C

**The problem:**
Given a TEXT, write a program that converts the TEXT to upper-case.

**Example**

**Input**

Hello John,

How are you?

Bye,

**Output**

HELLO JOHN,

HOW ARE YOU?

BYE,

**Here is my code:**

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<math.h>

void change(char s[]){
    for(int i=0;i< strlen(s);i++){
        s[i] = toupper(s[i]);
    }
}

int main(){
    while(1){
        char s[100];
        scanf("%s", s);
        if(s == )
        change(s);
        printf("%s\n", s);
    }
}
```

**the problem is** I dont know when to stop the input, when I run the program it never stops. My previous exercises would have something like "the end of the input is 1", but this one doesn't. Can you help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: `while (scanf("%s", s) == 1) { ... }` would exit if EOF was triggered. It isn't clear if that is what you are asking for or some other condition.

Comment: `scanf` with `%s` cannot save whitespaces. Using `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) { ... }` may be better.

Comment: You cannot use any of the `scanf` family of functions correctly unless you ***check the return***. You cannot fill an array with `scanf` (e.g. the `%s` or `%[..]` conversions specifiers), without also providing the *field-width* modifier to protect the array bounds. (e.g. `if (scanf ("%99s", s) != 1) { /* handle error */ }`) All of which is why it is recommended to take all user input with `fgets()` and trim the trailing `'\n'` from the buffer filled with, e.g. `s[strcspn (s, "\n")] = 0;` It avoids all pitfalls inherent with the use of `scanf()`.

Answer (score 3):

`scanf("%s", s);` is weak.  It only reads a *word* and is unbounded in how much is read.
Use `fgets()` to read a *line* of input into a *string*.

In any case, check the function return value and stop when the return value indicates no input.